# Are there any iPhone push apps that sound on silent?

Tags: iphone, apns

Are there any iPhone push apps that will still sound when the phone is set to silent/vibrate?

I've tried Prowl but it gets silenced. I'd like to have a way to find my phone more easily when I can't find it and it's on silent, and if I can send it a push notify that always sound it will solve my problem.

Comment: I don't think any iOS apps can override the sound setting of the phone for notifications. iCloud is, of course, an exception. See this Stack Overflow post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917131/iphone-is-it-possible-to-override-silent-mode-or-have-a-recursive-alert-sound

Comment: I take that back, this app might do just that: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/enotify/id429751714?mt=8

Answer (score 3):

Yes - Apple's find my iPhone app / service will sound the device despite mute, volume and do-not-disturb settings.

Comment: Also: Emergency/Government/AMBER alerts.

Comment: OK. In that case, this might be a bit more difficult than I'd hoped. Does anyone have any ideas on how I could programatically sound one of these alerts? One way would be to make a program to log in to iCloud to do it - but are there any easier ways?

Comment: The referenced alerts are known as WEA (Wireless Emergency Alerts) and must be generated from approved organizations and sent directly to FEMA using a security token. FEMA then filters these alerts before they are sent on to the mobile carriers for distribution. The only reason I know this is because I have recently been looking into doing the same thing, myself. See the following: [FEMA WEA FAQ](https://www.fema.gov/frequently-asked-questions-wireless-emergency-alerts) and [Details on WEA distribution flow](https://backchannel.com/our-cell-phone-alerts-will-be-hacked-2dd01ff8b54b#.8p3eqm1os)

Answer (score 2):

The Tile app (https://www.thetileapp.com/) does this when you click on the tile. So yes it is possible for third party apps to override silent.

Comment: Great answer. I've started using Tiles in the last few months and love them.

Answer (score 0):

Apps are only allowed to override silent through user interaction. (example. youtube app can override silence because you started the video).

Any app that dares send a push notification that overrides silence without a VERY good reason (a true emergency/amber alert/etc) will be denied by Apple. Don't even bother trying.